# Summarizing values where a summed column is exceeded within a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains position data relating to an employee. An employee may have more than one active position and the split can be defined by setting the percentage that applies. Positions have a start date and a end date. The default end date is 2099 which means the end hasn't been specified (on-going).

The data is entered through an ERP system and it's possible to exceed 100% during a given date range.

I want to build a query to summarize how many employees there are in each company that have position percentage split that exceed 100%. Only for active employee's though.

I have put together some sample data in Fiddle to illustrate this - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0e36d9

EDIT: Here is some sample data:

| status | company | EmpId | PositionCode | PositionPerc | Date_From | Date_To |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ACTIVE | EN | 1234 | 001 | 100 | 2012-06-12T00:00:00Z | 2021-01-12T00:00:00Z |
| ACTIVE | EN | 1234 | 002 | 100 | 2021-01-13T00:00:00Z | 2099-12-31T00:00:00Z |
| ACTIVE | EN | 4321 | 001 | 80 | 2019-06-17T00:00:00Z | 2099-12-31T00:00:00Z |
| ACTIVE | EN | 4321 | 003 | 30 | 2021-03-10T00:00:00Z | 2099-12-31T00:00:00Z |
| ACTIVE | EN | 7811 | 002 | 100 | 2019-06-17T00:00:00Z | 2020-11-12T00:00:00Z |
| ACTIVE | NO | 2234 | 002 | 50 | 2019-06-17T00:00:00Z | 2099-12-31T00:00:00Z |
| ACTIVE | NO | 2234 | 005 | 50 | 2020-02-21T00:00:00Z | 2099-12-31T00:00:00Z |
| ACTIVE | GB | 4121 | 001 | 100 | 2021-01-17T00:00:00Z | 2099-12-31T00:00:00Z |
| ACTIVE | GB | 4121 | 006 | 100 | 2021-04-17T00:00:00Z | 2099-12-31T00:00:00Z |
| ACTIVE | EN | 5551 | 001 | 50 | 2015-06-17T00:00:00Z | 2099-12-31T00:00:00Z |
| ACTIVE | EN | 5551 | 003 | 60 | 2021-03-10T00:00:00Z | 2099-12-31T00:00:00Z |

I'm trying to get the data back like this:

| Company | Emps_that_exceed |
| --- | --- |
| EN | 2 |
| NO | 0 |
| GB | 1 |

I would really appreciate any help.
I've tried to search on this but I'm struggling to describe it accurately enough to get anything useful back.

I know it's going to be something along the lines of

> ```
> select client, SUM(select....) from positiondata group by client
> ```

I've not had to do a query like this before.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to unpivot the data so you can do a cumulative sum.  On the day after the "to" date, you subtract the `positionperc` amount.

Then, just summarize by company to get the total employees who are in excess:

```
with ced as (
      select pd.company, pd.empid, v.date, sum(v.positionperc) as positionperc,
             sum(sum(v.positionperc)) over (partition by pd.company, pd.empid order by v.date) as total_positionperc
      from positiondata pd cross apply
           (values (pd.date_from, pd.positionperc),
                   (dateadd(day, 1, pd.date_to), - pd.positionperc)
           ) v(date, positionperc)
      group by pd.company, pd.empid, date
     )
select company,
       count(distinct case when total_positionperc > 100 then empid end)
from ced
group by company;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9c43507a42edf4bdee8cdd46dbce314f) is a db<>fiddle.